# Extract directory path and filename

Tags: shell, unix

I have a variable which has the directory path, along with the file name. I want to extract the filename alone from the Unix directory path and store it in a variable.

```
fspec="/exp/home1/abc.txt"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract File Basename Without Path and Extension in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664740/extract-file-basename-without-path-and-extension-in-bash)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Use the [basename](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_basename.htm) command to extract the filename from the path:

```
[/tmp]$ export fspec=/exp/home1/abc.txt 
[/tmp]$ fname=`basename $fspec`
[/tmp]$ echo $fname
abc.txt
```

Answer (score 34):

bash to get file name

```
fspec="/exp/home1/abc.txt" 
filename="${fspec##*/}"  # get filename
dirname="${fspec%/*}" # get directory/path name
```

other ways

awk

```
$ echo $fspec | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'
abc.txt
```

sed

```
$ echo $fspec | sed 's/.*\///'
abc.txt
```

using IFS

```
$ IFS="/"
$ set -- $fspec
$ eval echo \${${#@}}
abc.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for how to get the path and file names using Bash string manipulation! I’ve been searching for these precise cases for hours!

Answer (score 15):

You can simply do:

```
base=$(basename "$fspec")
```

Comment: And, if you need the path, too, use dirname: `fpath=$(dirname $fspec)`

Answer (score 4):

`dirname "/usr/home/theconjuring/music/song.mp3"`
will yield
    `/usr/home/theconjuring/music`.

Answer (score 3):

bash:

```
fspec="/exp/home1/abc.txt"
fname="${fspec##*/}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $fspec | tr "/" "\n"|tail -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using bash "here string":

```
$ fspec="/exp/home1/abc.txt" 
$ tr  "/"  "\n"  <<< $fspec | tail -1
abc.txt
$ filename=$(tr  "/"  "\n"  <<< $fspec | tail -1)
$ echo $filename
abc.txt
```

The benefit of the "here string" is that it avoids the need/overhead of running an `echo` command. In other words, the "here string" is internal to the shell. That is:

```
$ tr <<< $fspec
```

as opposed to:

```
$ echo $fspec | tr
```