# Extract file basename without path and extension in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, filenames

Given file names like these:

```
/the/path/foo.txt
bar.txt
```

I hope to get:

```
foo
bar
```

Why this doesn't work?

```
#!/bin/bash

fullfile=$1
fname=$(basename $fullfile)
fbname=${fname%.*}
echo $fbname
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: This code should work *in most cases* as long as the value of `$1` is actually what you think it is. However, it is subject to [word splitting](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/wordsplit) and [filename expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) due to improper [quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Comment: Closer @tripleee:  this is not a duplicate of [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/965053/6136214).  The other more complex Q requires the extension and filename be *separate*.  If anything, the other Q. is an elaboration of this more basic one.

Comment: @agc The answers seem very similar, but the older question has more of them. Can you explain why you think these should be kept separate?

Comment: @tripleee Users interested in the simpler problem might be needlessly confused by the added or differing code required to solve the more complex problem.

Comment: Did you read the answers to the other question? Out of the top five, four very distinctly demonstrate how to do exactly this, and explain the options, most of them quite succinctly. I'm happy to be convinced if you can point to actual differences, but I'm not seeing them. Perhaps raise this on [meta] for broader visibility.

Comment: Try this one-liner: `fname=$(basename "${1%.*}")`

Comment: I never understood why, on stack overflow, we close different questions when they have overlapping answers. Users search for a question, not an answer, and will never land that the "correct" question if they are not already aware of the similarity.  The site won't work as a `key → value` store if we keep deleting distinct keys that map to similar values.

Answer (score 833, accepted):

You don't have to call the external `basename` command. Instead, you could use the following commands:

```
$ s=/the/path/foo.txt
$ echo "${s##*/}"
foo.txt
$ s=${s##*/}
$ echo "${s%.txt}"
foo
$ echo "${s%.*}"
foo
```

Note that this solution should work in all recent (*post 2004*) *POSIX* compliant shells, (e.g. `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, etc.).

Source: [Shell Command Language 2.6.2 Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)

More on bash String Manipulations:  http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue18/bash.html

Comment: fantastic answer...  bash String Manipulations ( like `${s##*/}` ) are explained here http://linuxgazette.net/18/bash.html

Comment: @chim have you found an updated reference to your link? It's dead.

Comment: @Droogans found it after some digging :) http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue18/bash.html didn't realise I had 27 upvotes on this comment :)

Comment: Very handy, used this with file expansion and select. Example: `options=~/path/user.*` and then `select result in ${options[@]##*/};`

Comment: Is there a way to combine `##*/` at `%.*` (by nesting or piping or whatnot) arrive at foo directly?

Comment: BTW, TLDP's documentation isn't very well maintained; http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100 might be better references.

Comment: @bongbang, no; bash doesn't allow PEs to be nested. (zsh does, but it's pretty much alone in that).

Comment: doesn't work in ubuntu bash script with output as described

Comment: @bongbang - You can have everything in one line, with a Little variation on this post, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36341390/2707864.

Comment: Linux Gazette link is now broken: LG #18 is now available via http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue18/bash.html

Comment: FYI, worked also on `zsh`.

Comment: Documentation is also available via `man -P "less -p 'Parameter Expansion'" bash`

Comment: @chim the mentioned link is dead. here is archived version https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20111026140412/http://linuxgazette.net:80/18/bash.html

Comment: How do you do this in `fish`?

Comment: What happen if my path is something like `user/my_folder/[this_is_my_file]*`? 
What I obtain when I follow these steps is `[this_is_my_file]*`

Comment: this needs an explanation for what each step does, this answer is very hard to apply to other solutions otherwise!

Comment: I know in most cases parameter substitution is enough for the case, but they don't take care of the edge cases. `basename /path/name/` will give `name`, but `${var##*/}` will give ''. `dirname /path` will give '/', but `${var%/*}` give ''. Sure we can normalize the path before and after, but we have to write far more code to reach the reliability.

Comment: What does # stand for?

Comment: How to get `foo` via single command? I.e. how to correctly merge `s=${s##*/}` into `echo "${s%.*}"`?

Comment: For `/path/to/file.txt` I get `/path/to/file` (withouth the `txt`and not just `file`, Ubuntu user here.

Answer (score 377):

The [basename](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/basename.html) command has two different invocations; in one, you specify just the path, in which case it gives you the last component, while in the other you also give a suffix that it will remove. So, you can simplify your example code by using the second invocation of basename. Also, be careful to correctly quote things:

```
fbname=$(basename "$1" .txt)
echo "$fbname"
```

Comment: Is there a way of making it remove any suffix?

Comment: @handuel Unfortunately, `basename` does not support wildcards. Providing a second argument will only remove that exact literal string from the end.

Comment: On machines with basename 8.4, it works just as just as specified in this answer, but for me (with basename 8.22 from GNU coreutils) this worked as `basename -s <extension> <filename>`.

Comment: @w4etwetewtwet - You can have `basename` remove any extension, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36341390/2707864

Comment: if the name needs quoting, than it should be: `fbname="$(basename "$1" .txt)"`

Comment: +2 for this - simple and readable.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio It's not `basename` that is removing the extension, it's `bash` expansion. And that's then the same solution as @ghostdog74. It IS impossible to remove any extension with `basename` **only**.

Answer (score 85):

A combination of basename and cut works fine, even in case of double ending like `.tar.gz`:

```
fbname=$(basename "$fullfile" | cut -d. -f1)
```

Would be interesting if this solution needs less arithmetic power than Bash Parameter Expansion.

Comment: This is my preferred way - with the minor change of using `$(..)`  - so this becomes:

`fbname=$(basename "$fullfile" | cut -d. -f1)`

Comment: This is a nice solution in that it will snip *all* (dot) extensions.

Comment: If a file has dots elsewhere in the name, this would truncate it incorrectly.  This may work better: `fbname=$(basename "$fullfile" | sed -r 's|^(.*?)\.\w+$|\1|')`.  More choices: : `'s|^(.*?)\..+$|\1|'`, `'s|^(.*?)\.[^\.]+$|\1|'`.

Comment: Real thanks for real useful answer!

Answer (score 54):

Here are oneliners:

1. `$(basename "${s%.*}")`
2. `$(basename "${s}" ".${s##*.}")`

I needed this, the same as asked by bongbang and w4etwetewtwet.

Example:

```
$ s=/the/path/foo.txt
$ echo "$(basename "${s%.*}")"
foo
$ echo "$(basename "${s}" ".${s##*.}")"
foo
```

Answer (score 27):

Pure `bash`, no `basename`, no variable juggling.  Set a string and `echo`:

```
p=/the/path/foo.txt
echo "${p//+(*\/|.*)}"
```

Output:

```
foo
```

Note: the `bash` **extglob** option must be "on", (*Ubuntu* sets **extglob** "on" by default), if it's not, do:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

---

Walking through the `${p//+(*\/|.*)}`:

1. `${p` -- start with *$p*.
2. `//` substitute every instance of the pattern that follows.
3. `+(` match *one or more* of the *pattern list* in parenthesis, (*i.e.* until item #7 below).
4. *1st* pattern: `*\/` matches anything before a literal "`/`" char.
5. pattern separator `|` which in this instance acts like a [logical OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction).
6. *2nd* pattern: `.*` matches anything after a literal "`.`" -- that is, in `bash` the "`.`" is just a period char, and *not* [a regex dot](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html).
7. `)` end *pattern list*.
8. `}` end parameter expansion.  With a string substitution, there's usually another `/` there, followed by a replacement string.  But since there's no `/` there, the matched patterns are substituted with nothing; this deletes the matches.

Relevant `man bash` background:

1. *pattern substitution*:

> ```
>   ${parameter/pattern/string}
>           Pattern substitution.  The pattern is expanded to produce a pat
>           tern just as in pathname expansion.  Parameter is  expanded  and
>           the  longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with
>           string.  If pattern begins with /, all matches  of  pattern  are
>           replaced   with  string.   Normally  only  the  first  match  is
>           replaced.  If pattern begins with #, it must match at the begin‐
>           ning of the expanded value of parameter.  If pattern begins with
>           %, it must match at the end of the expanded value of  parameter.
>           If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the / fol
>           lowing pattern may be omitted.  If parameter is @ or *, the sub
>           stitution  operation  is applied to each positional parameter in
>           turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter  is
>           an  array  variable  subscripted  with  @ or *, the substitution
>           operation is applied to each member of the array  in  turn,  and
>           the expansion is the resultant list.
> ```

2. *extended pattern matching*:

> ```
>   If the extglob shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin, several
>    extended  pattern  matching operators are recognized.  In the following
>    description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated
>    by a |.  Composite patterns may be formed using one or more of the fol
>    lowing sub-patterns:
>
>           ?(pattern-list)
>                  Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
>           *(pattern-list)
>                  Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
>           +(pattern-list)
>                  Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
>           @(pattern-list)
>                  Matches one of the given patterns
>           !(pattern-list)
>                  Matches anything except one of the given patterns
> ```

Answer (score 13):

Here is another (more complex) way of getting either the filename or extension, first use the `rev` command to invert the file path, cut from the first `.` and then invert the file path again, like this:

```
filename=`rev <<< "$1" | cut -d"." -f2- | rev`
fileext=`rev <<< "$1" | cut -d"." -f1 | rev`
```

Comment: I've never seen those triple angle bracket `<<<` doohickeys--what's that?

Comment: They are called "Here Strings" (more info [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html)), basically it takes the input as a string and feed it to your program as it was reading through stdin.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to play nice with Windows file paths (under Cygwin) you can also try this:

```
fname=${fullfile##*[/|\\]}
```

This will account for backslash separators when using BaSH on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative that I came up with to extract an extension, using the posts in this thread with my own small knowledge base that was more familiar to me.

```
ext="$(rev <<< "$(cut -f "1" -d "." <<< "$(rev <<< "file.docx")")")"
```

Note: Please advise on my use of quotes; it worked for me but I might be missing something on their proper use (I probably use too many).

Comment: You do not need a single quote, you try to do the same as: `rev <<< file.docx | cut -f1 -d. | rev` just without the quotes and without the nested sub shells. Also I don't think the above can work at all.

Answer (score -16):

Use the basename command. Its manpage is here:  http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?basename

Comment: He is using `basename`, but that's not his problem.