# "batch" files in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ffmpeg, file-extension

I want to make a "batch" file so to say for some bash commands (convert.sh). I think it would be best to describe the situation. i have a $#!^ ton of mp4 videos that i want converted into mp3's. it would take me an unreasonable amount of time to convert them using `ffmpeg -i /root/name\ of\ video.mp4 /name\ of\ video.mp3` for every single video. not to mention the fact that all the file names are long and complicated so typos are a possibility. so i want to know how to make a shell script (for bash) that will take every file with the extension `.mp4` and convert it to a `.mp3` with the same name one by one. as in it converts one then when it done it moves on to the next one. im using a lightweight version of linux so any 3rd part soft probably wont work so i need to use ffmpeg...

many thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide

PS: i cant seem to get the formatting sytax on the website to work right so if somone can format this for me and maybe post a link to a manual on how it works that would be much appreciated =)

PPS: i understand that questions about using the ffmpeg command should be asked on superuser however since i dont so much have any questions about the specific command and this relates more to scripting a bash file i figure this is the right place

Comment: There are formatting instructions in the sidebar on the edit/post page.  You can also get help text by hovering over the tools.

Comment: Seems like you haven't taken a basic intro to shell scripting. Try googling "bash script tutorial"

Comment: @BjørneMalmanger see iv tried that kinda thing but all i can ever find is stuff on making directories and moving files.....

Comment: Read http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ (it does have imperfections, but it will teach you a lot); also learn about `at`, `batch`, `crontab`, `nohup`, `screen` .... commands

Comment: Also see the [FFmpeg MP3 Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Encoding%20VBR%20%28Variable%20Bit%20Rate%29%20mp3%20audio).

Answer (score 1):

A `bash` for loop should do it for you in no time:

```bsh
SRC_DIR=/root
DST_DIR=/somewhereelse
for FILE in ${SRC_DIR}/*.mp4
do
    ffmpeg -i "${FILE}" "${DST_DIR}/$(basename \"${FILE}\" .mp4).mp3"
done
```

Sorry - I don't know the `ffmpeg` command line options, so I just copied exactly what's in your post.

Comment: almost there... it gave me a problem with having sapces in the names.... said `/root/asr143: no such file or directory`

Comment: @Konner - I added some `""` in an edit that should fix that problem.

Comment: Very nice... for some reason it gave me an issue with the -o option so i removed it and now am on my way to a seamless and pain free conversion =) thank you very much for you prompt and helpful response =)

Comment: Sorry, dunno where that -o came from.  A quick glance at the ffmpeg docs says you don't need that.

Comment: i spoke too soon (isnt that a wonderful thing) its trying to name all the files ".mp3" without the full names

Comment: Hmm... Add an `echo` in and start debugging I guess.  Good luck!

Comment: Instead of `basename` you can use [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073).

Answer (score 1):

1) use find:

```
find . -name \*.mp4 | xargs ./my_recode_script.sh
```

2) my_recode_script.sh - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664740/extract-file-basename-without-path-and-extension-in-bash)
   so you can easily change the extension for output file name

the rest is trivial scripting job:

```
ffmpeg -i $name $new_name # in my_recode_script.sh after changing extension
```

this is enough for one-time script, if you want something reusable, wrap it with yet another script which receive path to dir, extensions from which to which to recode and call other parts :)