# How can I locate a specific file in a directory within a loop?

Tags: bash, unix, loops, filenames

I'm having trouble pointing to a specific file containing part of the string of another file in another directory.

If you look at the following command, lets say I have a file abc.foo in ./A, I need to apply a function by using abc_extendedname1.jpeg which is in ./B

```
for file in ./A/*; 

do echo $file;
function $file -opt ./B/${file%.foo}_extendedname1.jpeg ./B/${file%.foo}_extendedname2.jpeg;

done
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: FYI, `function` is a reserved keyword. Saying `my_function` would be clearer.

Comment: so basically you are trying to extract the basename w/o extension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664740/extract-file-basename-without-path-and-extension-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for file in ./A/*; do
  basename=${file##*/}
  basename_noext=${basename%.*}
  echo "$file"
  your_function "$file" -out \
    "./B/${basename_noext}_extendedname1.jpeg" \
    "./B/${basename_noext}_extendedname2.jpeg"
done
```

Comment: You're a life saver! Works beautifully. So I take it my mistake was in using $file without removing the directory info?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. By the way, next time, try using `set -x` within your script (or `bash -x` to start it) to see what your script is doing wrong. (For bigger scripts it's worth also learning how to use `PS4` to include line numbers and such in that trace, but... well, baby steps).

Answer (score -1):

try

```
export d="`pwd`"
find ./A/*|while read file
do
    echo "$file"
    if [ -f  "$d/B/${file}_extendedname1.jpeg" ]
    then
        echo "$d/B/${file}_extendedname1.jpeg" found
    fi
done
```

Comment: Needs more quotes -- right now, this won't correctly handle filenames with spaces.

Comment: ...and backticks are more or less deprecated, use `$(...)` instead

Comment: And it will break if the working directory (not just a filename) contains spaces, and [pipelining into a loop will break as soon as it's called upon to increment a variable (or something else with side effects)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#grep_foo_bar_.7C_while_read_-r.3B_do_.28.28count.2B-.2B-.29.29.3B_done), and the semicolon after the first `echo` is useless and looks like a PHP coder's work, and the `export ` is unnecessary, and `$d` is unnecessary and can be replaced by `.` (making the backquotes unnecessary), and it's lucky that's all I can see because I'm out of characters.

Comment: ...also, using `read` instead of `read -r` means that backspaces inside the filenames are interpreted instead of read literally. And using `find`'s default `-print` behavior means that filenames with newlines in their names won't work right (yup, they're legal on UNIX), and... so forth.