# Bash extracting file basename from long path

Tags: bash, filenames, glob

In `bash` I am trying to `glob` a list of files from a directory to give as input to a program. However I would also like to give this program the list of filenames

```
files="/very/long/path/to/various/files/*.file"
```

So I could use it like that.

```
prompt> program -files $files -names $namelist
```

If the `glob` gives me :

```
/very/long/path/to/various/files/AA.file /very/long/path/to/various/files/BB.file /very/long/path/to/various/files/CC.file /very/long/path/to/various/files/DD.file /very/long/path/to/various/files/ZZ.file
```

I'd like to get the list of AA BB CC DD ZZ to feed my program without the long pathname and file extension. 
However I have no clue on how start there ! Any hint much appreciated !

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's better to use an array to hold the filenames. A string variable will not handle filenames which contain spaces.

Also, you don't need to use the `basename` command. Instead use bash's built-in string manipulation.

Try this:

```
files=( /very/long/path/to/various/files/*.file )
for file in "${files[@]}"
do
  filename="${file##*/}"
  filenameWithoutExtension="${filename%.*}"
  echo "$filenameWithoutExtension"
done
```

Comment: could you please give me the reference from where i can read all these string matching formats...

Comment: Can you at least explain why one shouldn't use basename? And what did that string manipulation pattern actually do / match?

Comment: Essentially looping over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664740/extract-file-basename-without-path-and-extension-in-bash

Answer (score 9):

Solution with `basename` for your question

```
for file in $files
do
  file_name=$(basename $file)
  file_name_witout_ext=${file_name%.file}
done
```

**edit (generic way to extract filename without (single) extension)**

```
for file in $files
do
  file_name=$(basename $file)
  file_name_witout_ext=${file_name%.*}
done
```

Another thing that can happen is to have filename like "archive.tar.gz". In this case you will have two (or multiple extension). You can then use a more greddy operator

```
for file in $files
do
  file_name=$(basename $file)
  file_name_witout_ext=${file_name%%.*}
done
```

Comment: +1 You can be more general using `filename_without_extension="${filename%.*}"`, taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/1983854

Comment: excat fedorqui, it may be a good thing. I just stick to the OP parameters.

Answer (score 3):

It's simpler like this:

```
files=(/very/long/path/to/various/files/*.file)
names=("${files[@]##*/}") names=("${names[@]%.*}")
progname -files "${files[@]}" -names "${names[@]}"
```

Or if you could only pass them as a single argument:

```
progname -files "${files[*]}" -names "${names[*]}"
```