# Delete files in one directory that do not exist in another directory or its child directories

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I am still a newbie in shell scripting and trying to come up with a simple code. Could anyone give me some direction here. Here is what I need.

```
Files in path 1: /tmp
100abcd
200efgh 
300ijkl

Files in path2: /home/storage
backupfile_100abcd_str1
backupfile_100abcd_str2
backupfile_200efgh_str1
backupfile_200efgh_str2
backupfile_200efgh_str3
```

Now I need to delete file 300ijkl in /tmp as the corresponding backup file is not present in /home/storage. The /tmp file contains more than 300 files. I need to delete the files in /tmp for which the corresponding backup files are not present and the file names in /tmp will match file names in /home/storage or directories under /home/storage.

Appreciate your time and response.

Answer (score 3):

You can also approach the deletion using `grep` as well. You can loop though the files in `/tmp` checking with `ls` piped to `grep`, and deleting if there is not a match:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" -o -z "$2" ] && {  ## validate input
    printf "error: insufficient input. Usage: %s tmpfiles storage\n" ${0//*\//}
    exit 1
}

for i in "$1"/*; do
    fn=${i##*/}  ## strip path, leaving filename only
    
    ## if file in backup matches filename, skip rest of loop
    ls "${2}"* | grep -q "$fn" &>/dev/null && continue
    
    printf "removing %s\n" "$i"
    # rm "$i" ## remove file
done
```

**Note:** the actual removal is commented out above, test and insure there are no unintended consequences before preforming the actual delete. Call it passing the path to `tmp` (without trailing `/`) as the first argument and with `/home/storage` as the second argument:

```
$ bash scriptname /path/to/tmp /home/storage
```

Comment: I considered that initially, but since it would be far slower (running both `ls` and `grep` for *each* filename), took the hint from the linux+shell tags.

Comment: The other alternative would be to hold all filenames in `/home/storage` in an array and then simply `grep -q "$fn" &>/dev/null <<<${array[@]}` using a **herestring** to avoid `ls` on each file.

Comment: Thank you Thomas and David. Really appreciate your response on this. Saved me a lot of time :-). Long way to go for me. I tried David's code and it worked. Will try the other one too. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey just wanted to point out the above code will have issues with file and folder names containing spaces. To fix this issue, simply change the line `ls ${2}* | grep -q $fn` to `ls "${2}" | grep -q "$fn"`

Comment: @Eagnir - good catch. Always worth making an old post better. I know better. When you get enough rep to edit, at least with my shell posts, feel free to fix minor oversights like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by

- making a list of the files in `/home/storage`
- testing each filename in `/tmp` to see if it is in the list from `/home/storage`

Given the linux+shell tags, one might use bash:

- make the list of files from `/home/storage` an *associative array*
- make the subscript of the array the filename

Here is a sample script to illustrate (`$1` and `$2` are the parameters to pass to the script, i.e., `/home/storage` and `/tmp`):

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A InTarget

while read path
do
    name=${path##*/}
    InTarget[$name]=$path
done < <(find $1 -type f)

while read path
do
    name=${path##*/}
    [[ -z ${InTarget[$name]} ]] && rm -f $path
done < <(find $2 -type f)
```

It uses two interesting shell features:

- **`name=${path##*/}`** is a [POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) feature which allows the script to perform the `basename` function without an extra process (per filename).  That makes the script faster.
- **`done < <(find $2 -type f)`** is a [bash feature](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) which lets the script read the list of filenames from `find` without making the assignments to the array run in a subprocess.  Here the reason for using the feature is that if the array is updated in a subprocess, it would have no effect on the array value in the script which is passed to the second loop.

For related discussion:

- *[Extract File Basename Without Path and Extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664740/extract-file-basename-without-path-and-extension-in-bash)*
- *[Bash Script: While-Loop Subshell Dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726764/bash-script-while-loop-subshell-dilemma)*

Answer (score 0):

I spent some really nice time on this today because I needed to delete files which have same name but different extensions, so if anyone is looking for a quick implementation, here you go:

```
 #!/bin/bash 
 
 # We need some reference to files which we want to keep and not delete, 
 # let's assume you want to keep files in first folder with jpeg, so you 
 # need to map it into the desired file extension first.  
 FILES_TO_KEEP=`ls -1 ${2} | sed 's/\.pdf$/.jpeg/g'`
 #iterate through files in first argument path
    for file in ${1}/*; do
        # In my case, I did not want to do anything with directories, so let's continue cycle when hitting one.
        if [[ -d $file ]]; then
         continue
        fi 
        # let's omit path from the iterated file with baseline so we can compare it to the files we want to keep
        NAME_WITHOUT_PATH=`basename $file` 
        # I use mac which is equal to having poor quality clts
        # when it comes to operating with strings,
        # this should be safe check to see if FILES_TO_KEEP contain NAME_WITHOUT_PATH
        if [[ $FILES_TO_KEEP == *"$NAME_WITHOUT_PATH"* ]];then
            echo "Not deleting: $NAME_WITHOUT_PATH"
        else
        # If it does not contain file from the other directory, remove it.
            echo "deleting: $NAME_WITHOUT_PATH"
            rm -rf $file
        fi
    done
```

Usage: `sh deleteDifferentFiles.sh path/from/where path/source/of/truth`