# Basename command in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to run the following as part of a application start script:

```
for file in $TEMPLATE_FOLDER/*
do
    filename='basename $file'
    echo "Processing $filename"

    if [ -f "$CONF_FOLDER/$filename" ]
    then
        echo "Using existing $filename"
    else
        echo "Creating $filename from template $file"
        cp $file $CONF_FOLDER
    fi
done
```

But the output is:

```
Processing basename $file
Creating basename $file from template ../conf/templates/conf-TEST/log4j.xml
```

The basename command is not evaluated and is just printed out.

When i run the command from the prompt it works fine.

Bash version:

```
bash -version
GNU bash, version 3.00.16(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Can anyone see what i am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: [Get basename of filename or directory name](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-get-basename-of-filename-or-directory-name/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the system has `bash`, and the script works with `bash`, first change line #1 of the script from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`.

Then change this line:

```
filename='basename $file'
```

To this:

```
filename=`basename $file`
```

Comment: @monokrome, True, but the OP's system *does* have `basename`.   For a pure `bash` method  please try `filename="${file//+(*\/)}"` and refer to [Extract file basename without path and extension in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664740/extract-file-basename-without-path-and-extension-in-bash/38277789#38277789).