# Need to split the file path/directory and use it as an argument using shell script

Tags: shell

I need to split the file path/directory and use it as an argument using shell script.

I have a file path: `/home/ubuntu/testscriptsfolder/jmx/*.jmx`
and need to get only `*.jmx` in my variable so that I can pass it as an argument in one of my run commands.

Please suggest how it is achievable in shell script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unix shell script - extract file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536046/unix-shell-script-extract-file-name)

Comment: You could try parameter substitution using ##

Answer (score 2):

These commands are useful for that:

```
$ basename /path/to/name
name
$ dirname /path/to/name
/path/to
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing info. However when tried with basename /path/to/name, can get only one file name whereas I have to iterate through all the files (10 .jmx files are present). Please suggest.